# What is the Edit Mode Panel component?

Tags: sxa

SXA comes with an Edit Mode Panel component in the Toolbox. 
Adding it to the page just seems to add a blank placeholder.
What is it for and what's an example use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `Edit Mode Panel` creates a placeholder to embed other renderings that are visible to authors in Edit mode only.

So a use case might be where you want some fields on a page easily editable without forcing the author to go back into the content editor, or maybe a component is not ready for production yet, so you *could* hide it until read with this panel.

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-renderings-and-rendering-variants.html#UUID-8ddc0bb8-f029-3f4b-1f0d-60ee1e102959_id__Page_structure